# Advancing a 'for-loop' with true-false statement

Tags: r

I am simulating mark-recapture data.  In the abbreviated example below, I have a matrix with 10 individuals (rows) over 3 sampling periods (columns).  I have a matrix tracking if they are alive (1) or dead (0), if they are present in the study area (1) or not (0), and the matrix I am trying to fill out, which states if they are captured (1) or not (0) each period.

In my real example, I have 180 columns over 1000 individuals, and I want to speed up my for loop.  In the loop below (where I loop through each individual and each row), I want to be able to jump ahead to the next individual once the current individual is found to be dead.  I tried doing this with an if/else statement, where if 'is.alive=/1', it would advance the value of 'j' (which iterates through sampling periods) to the final value of 3.  I thought this would get me to advance to the next individual, but I end up getting

```
"Error in ifelse(is.alive == 1, ifelse(is.pres == 1, ifelse(runif(1) <=:
  unused argument(s) (j = 3)"
```

Any advice?

```
survival.mat<-matrix(1,10,3) #Matrix tracking 10 individuals (rows) over 3 time periods (columns)
survival.mat[c(2,4,6),c(2,3)]<-0 #Creating some deaths (1=alive, 0=dead)
present.mat<-survival.mat #A new matrix to see if individuals are present for capture
present.mat[c(1,5,8),2]<-0 #Making some alive individuals unavailable (0) for capture
capture.mat<-matrix(0,10,3) #A matrix to test if individuals were captured
capture.mat[,1]<-1 #All individuals captured on first occasion, since this is when they are marked
cap.prob<-0.5 #our probability of capture


    for(i in 1:10){  #Iterating through the rows (each row is an individual)
        for(j in 2:3){ #Iterating through columns (each column is a time period)

        is.alive <- survival.mat[i,j]
        is.pres <- present.mat[i,j]
        ifelse(is.alive==1,  #If the individual is alive, continue, if not jump ahead to 'j=3' which is what I am using to try to advance the loop
                                ifelse(is.pres==1,ifelse(runif(1)<=cap.prob,capture.mat[i,j]<-1,NA),NA)#If it is alive (previous statement), is it present for capture?  If so, run a capture coinflip.
                                 ,j=3) #Trying to advance the simulation to j = 3 if the individual is not alive
                                }
                        }
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do a `break`?

Comment: I've found [this blogpost](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2008/12/use-equals-or-arrow-for-assignment.html) on assignment operators helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So there's two things going on here:

1. `ifelse` wants to return a value, but instead you're telling it to run a task (assignment operator `=`). If you'd like to change `j` to 3 inside of ifelse, you can do either:

   ```
   ifelse(cond, true stuff, {j=3 ; j})
   ifelse(cond, true stuff, j <- 3) ## assigns 3 to j but also returns j
   ```
2. The way `for` loops work, you don't need to change the value of `j` in order to go to the next loop, `R` takes care of that (different from other languages in that way). The command `next` (NOT `break`) will take you to the next iteration, so do:

   ```
   ifelse(cond, truestuff, next)
   ```

Comment: I've found something interesting.  While your approach works, I find the code actually runs faster if I only do an 'If' statement, without the corresponding 'else(j<-3)' if the individual is not alive

Comment: Right - doing it that way will make it continue the iteration ignoring the "true stuff", so if there's nothing but "true stuff", then you can just use the `if` part. I don't think it'd be any faster, but you can use `system.time` to check.

Comment: Yup, I used system.time() to check, and using 'If' without a 'false' statement was faster than using an 'Ifelse' when the false statement was to advance the value of 'j'